# How to use Exception in Asp.net MVC

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc-3

I created MVC project which save some XML data in file and read this data and shows to user. But I want add block try{} catch{} in some places, for example where I read XML Document and if XML -is not correct I want show it as Exception. But I don't know how do it, because all what I found it is Exception like 404 Error and others. 
So, this is my XmlWorker class, where I do some operations with XML. How to show Exceptions in  Mvc when something go wrong?

```
   public static XElement GetElementById(XDocument xDocument, int id)
    {
        Debug.Assert(id != null);
        Debug.Assert(xDocument != null);

        XElement selectedElementForEdit = xDocument.Element("Addresses")
                                                  .Elements("Address")
                                                  .Where(x => Int32.Parse(x.Element("Id").Value) == id)
                                                  .SingleOrDefault();
        return selectedElementForEdit;
    }
```

In this case I can face to ArgumentNullExcpetion, so where I should show about it and How?

```
 public static void SaveChanges(Address address,string PathToXmlFile)
    {
        // Проверка входящих значений
        Debug.Assert(address != null);
        Debug.Assert(PathToXmlFile != null);

        XDocument loadedXDocumentForEdit = XDocument.Load(PathToXmlFile);
        XElement loadedXElementForEdit = GetElementById(loadedXDocumentForEdit, address);
        // Записать изменения в Xml элемент
        XElement changedElement=ConvertObjectAddressToXmlElementAddress(address, loadedXElementForEdit);
        changedElement.Save(PathToXmlFile);
        loadedXDocumentForEdit.Save(PathToXmlFile);
    }
```

This is Controller

```
          [HttpPost]
    [HandleError()]
    public ActionResult Edit(Address address)
    {
        XmlWorker.SaveChanges(address, PATH_TO_XML_FILE);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

I hope you understand what I mean

Comment: If I understand correctly, you just need `[HandleError(ExceptionType=typeof(ArgumentNullException), View="MyErrorView")]`

Comment: Thank you. But I have question. As you see I use [HandleError()] - is it common Exception for all errors? But if I want to clarify Exception I should just write like you recomended? And if I decided to use [HandleError()] I should write   <customErrors mode="On"/>

Comment: Yes, I believe that is correct.